# Reading token in ASP.net Core Razor pages WebApp

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages, azure-api-management, bearer-token

I have an asp.net core razor pages webapp hosted in Azure, Using app registration and AD, so far I can successfully log in, authenticate and generate a bearer token. I am trying to call an API in Azure APIM that has a  policy.

I can manually inspect the log in and copy the token value and call the API using postman. However I cannot use that token as a variable in my webapp to set my authorization header for my POST request. If I add a break point to the actions that are supposed to call the token I just get value : null.

So far I have tried all the docs and info I can find but always points to :

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly string _apiUrl;

    public IndexModel(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        _apiUrl = configuration["ApiUrl"]; // Replace with the URL of your API endpoint.
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "your_api_scope" });

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(_apiUrl);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // Process the API response as needed.
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle the unsuccessful response here.
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
{
 // Acquire the access token.
 string[] scopes = new string[]{"user.read"};
 string accessToken = await authorizationHeaderProvider.CreateAuthorizationHeaderForUserAsync(scopes);

 // Use the access token to call a protected web API.
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
 string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}
```

Both return null value on the token even though I can see the token was successfully created on log in

Comment: edit typo : I have a validate-jwt policy on the API in Azure APIM

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are have logged in and authenticated have you tried this:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    private IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;            
    }

    public async void OnGet()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        }

    }
}
```

Now you can construct a HttpClient and set that as a bearer token, something like:

```
var apiClient = new HttpClient();
        apiClient.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
```